# marking the contents of a directory read-only

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod

I'd like to mark a directory as read only in a way that would make it's contents read-only. Using chmod a=rx makes the directory read/executable only, so it and its contents can't be deleted. That's partway there, but it's still possible to modify the contents. chmod a=r prevents the reading of the contents.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for

```
chmod a-w -R your_directory
```

To prevent changes to files in a directory, you must remove the write attribute from the files themselves.

Comment: That does work, and I'm using that method right now. It has to disadvantage that to check the status of a directory, we have to check each file individually. It would be great if there was a way to lock the entire directory and just check that.

Comment: @jyoung What do you mean by `check the status of a directory`? It is about checking their content and make sure all files are read only? If so, you can use `Default ACLs` to inherit `read` perms on all files that are created under that directory.

Comment: I'm setting up a bash script, and I'd like to write something like if [ ! -w folder ]; then.... But, from the looks of things, it's probably necessary to do this test on every file in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr:

1. Set read-only recursively to the directory and all existing / new files inside:

   `sudo chmod a=r -R /path/to/the/folder/`
2. Set permissions on the directory itself so everyone can get into the directory

   `sudo chmod a=rx /path/to/the/folder/`

---

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, so I'll make this a thorough answer.

I refer to the [SS64 chmod page](https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) for a quick reference if ever I can't remember something about chmod.

Create a test directory in your home directory, then create a test file, and finally list the directory contents:

```
mkdir ~/testaubs
cd ~/testaubs
touch testfile.aubs
ls -l
```

> total 0
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 aubs aubs 0 Dec  4 03:19 testfile.aubs

This file has `read-write` for the **owner**, `read` for the **group** and `read` for **users** (anyone else).

From the parameters you provided, `a=rx`, you're allowing everyone to read the file, but also execute it.  The title of the question said **read only**.

If you run:

```
chmod a=rx testfile.aubs
ls -l
```

> total 0
>
> -r-xr-xr-x 1 aubs aubs 0 Dec  4 03:19 testfile.aubs

This file now has `read-execute` for the **owner**, `read-execute` for the **group** and `read-execute` for **users** (anyone else).

You can set the permissions for this file to `read` for everyone by running:

```
chmod a=r testfile.aubs
ls -l
```

> total 0
>
> -r--r--r-- 1 aubs aubs 0 Dec  4 03:19 testfile.aubs

No one (except root) can now make any changes to the file at all, even you.

The next problem now comes, when you create another file in the same directory:

```
touch testfile2.aubs
ls -l
```

> total 0
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 aubs aubs 0 Dec  4 03:35 testfile2.aubs
>
> -r--r--r-- 1 aubs aubs 0 Dec  4 03:19 testfile.aubs

The new `testfile2.aubs` file has inherited the permissions of its' parent directory that it sits in, which is `read-write` for the **owner**, `read` for the **group** and `read` for **users** (anyone else).

---

If you want to stop anyone from **creating** new files within the directory, you need to set the permissions on the parent directory too.

First, we'll check what those permissions are, so we'll go up one level and list all files, but restrict to only see the test directory:

```
cd ..
ls -l  | grep test
```

> drwxr-xr-x 2 aubs aubs 4096 Dec  4 03:35 test

We can see the parent directory has the permissions of `read-write-execute` for the **owner**, `read-execute` for the **group** and `read-execute` for **users** (anyone else).

We can set recursive permissions on all existing and new files inside the directory **owner**, **group** and **users** to have `read` only, but we'll need to elevate our permissions with `sudo` as we set the first file to `read` only for the **owner** (our account):

```
sudo chmod a=r -R test/
ls -l | grep test
```

> dr--r--r--  2 aubs aubs  4096 Dec  4 03:35 test

We can then set the permissions on the directory itself, so **owner**, **group** and **users** all have read-execute (they need execute so they can get in the directory, otherwise they'll get a `bash: cd: test/: Permission denied` error).  This also needs elevating permissions with `sudo`:

```
sudo chmod a=rx test/
ls -l | grep test
```

> dr-xr-xr-x 2 aubs aubs 4096 Dec  4 03:35 test

We had to use `sudo` for some of the above because when we removed 'write' from our account (owner) we would lose the permission to change it again!

Now we can get into the folder and list the contents (see everyone is `read` only):

```
cd test/
ls -l
```

> total 0
>
> -r--r--r-- 1 aubs aubs 0 Dec  4 03:35 testfile2.aubs
>
> -r--r--r-- 1 aubs aubs 0 Dec  4 03:19 testfile.aubs

but we can't create a new file:

```
touch testfile3.aubs
```

> touch: cannot touch 'testfile3.aubs': Permission denied

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply, I appreciate that. In this scenario, we can't create a new file in test, and we also can't modify the existing files because of the -R on the chmod command a few steps back. That's actually the state that I'd like to create. However, it's somewhat difficult to test for after the fact, since we'd have to test the permissions on ever file. For example, if the creator of the directory test had omitted the -R on the chmod command, then it would still be possible to modify the files contained in test.

Comment: You could find any files in a directory that aren't `read` only for everyone with with `find . -not -perm 444`.  The problem you have is a directory can have some permissions, but the files within the directory can have completely different permissions, unless you set them to be restrictive with the recursive -R, then set the directory permissions to let people get into it the directory.